# Get meta value when the page is a blog archive

Tags: custom-field, loop, metabox, post-meta, archive-template

I'm using custom metaboxes on my pages. For example: header icon.

I created a page for the news on my site. I selected it as a blog archive page under Settings->Reading page. Unfortunately I can't get the meta values for this page.

When I create a page for the blog archive is it uses the index.php or the page.php?

I tried to read the metafields using the page id, but unfortunately `global $post; echo $post->ID;` returned only the id of the first post in the loop.

What is the best way to read meta values on a page, when it's selected as a blog archive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_queried_object_ID()` will return the ID on the page for posts, or [`get_queried_object()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) will return the page object containing all its post fields.

Alternately, the ID of the blog page is stored in the option `page_for_posts`, which is internally how `get_queried_object` gets the ID of the post object to load.